# TFS2015 AutoCopy task

Tags: tfs-2015

I am looking for a way to copy only the triggering file(s) for a triggered task with TFS2015 Team Server.  I have a task setup as for Continuous Integration to get triggered for a check-in of file(s) for a Repository.....but I have only found to copy ALL files for the Repository to a separate server location.  I only want to copy the file(s) that triggered the CI task.  All other files on the separate server would still be up to date.  Seems like this should be easily done with the new TFS2015 Build options, but I can't find a way to do this specific operation.

Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 0):

There is no specific operation for this.

You would need to add a PowerShell task and write the PowerShell to move the diff between the locations.

You should also check http://marketplace.visualstudio.com for a pre-built task that can do this..

Comment: Thanks for your response.  Too bad the task can't access the triggering item.

Answer (score 0):

There is no out-of-the-box feature for this.

You could either use powershell script as *MrHinsh* suggested or write your own build task to achieve it. Details about how to write extensions for Visual Studio Team Services please refer this tutorial: [Add a build task](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/extensions/develop/add-build-task)

Some [related copy task](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/search?term=copy&target=VSTS&sortBy=Relevance) in Marketplace for your reference.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Patrick.  Yes, I am now investigating the Custom Build task route.  We have an on-premises TFS Server.  I assume it works the same.

Comment: Yes,it's working the same. In Team Foundation Server 2015 Update 2, we have enabled support for installing extensions. As mentioned above, there are two ways in which you can get these extensions: 1. You can download them from the Visual Studio Marketplace and upload them to a Team Foundation Server. 2. You can build your own extensions using the guidance above and upload them to a Team Foundation Server. If you are using on presmises TFS Server, suggest you to update the version to *update2* and above.